# Smooth transitions with the new "Pressable" component?

Tags: react-native, animation, expo, react-native-reanimated-v2

I've been using `TouchableOpacity` for ease of use in my react native project, but I'm interested in trying the new [`Pressable`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) component instead - given how flexible its API is.

However, while the new `Pressable` API gives me the ability to change things like `style` props based on a `pressed` state easily, there is no smooth/animated transition like there is with the opacity in `TouchableOpacity`! Instead, the transition happens instantly when pressed/unpressed.

What is the best way to use `Pressable` but also make a nice, smooth transition between the pressed/unpressed style changes? I assume I'll have to use the `Animated` API in some way? Does anyone have an example of this?

Comment: You can try https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-pressable-opacity

Comment: Oh interesting - thanks! It's great to see the source code for this as well as an example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Animated Api
Here is a example of Animated Api:

```js
import { Pressable, Animated, View } from "react-native";

const Component = () => {
  const animated = new Animated.Value(1);

  const fadeIn = () => {
    Animated.timing(animated, {
      toValue: 0.4,
      duration: 100,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };
  const fadeOut = () => {
    Animated.timing(animated, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 200,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Pressable onPressIn={fadeIn} onPressOut={fadeOut}>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            opacity: animated,
            backgroundColor: "red",
            padding: 50,
            borderRadius: 20,
          }}
        >
          <Text>Text</Text>
        </Animated.View>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Animated Api docs:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated

Also i recommend to check out reanimated library to create animation with native performance

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/

Comment: Thanks, useful to-go animation that looks like touchableOpacity.
However, it's unclear why the developers haven't added this functionality already to the component itself (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

With Reanimated v3

```js
import { Pressable } from 'react-native';
import Animated, { useSharedValue, withSpring } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const AnimatedPressable = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Pressable);

const Button = ({ children, onPress }) => {
  const opacity = useSharedValue(1);

  const handlePressIn = () => {
    opacity.value = withSpring(0.8);
  };

  const handlePressOut = () => {
    opacity.value = withSpring(1);
  };

  return (
    <AnimatedPressable
      onPressIn={handlePressIn}
      onPressOut={handlePressOut}
      style={{ opacity }}
    >
      {children}
    </AnimatedPressable>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more up-to-date example using React hooks and the Animated API. It also handles the `disabled` state

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Animated, Easing, Pressable, PressableProps } from 'react-native';

interface PressableWrapperProps extends PressableProps {
  disabledOpacity?: number;
  activeOpacity?: number;
  duration?: number;
}

const AnimatedPressable = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Pressable);

export const PressableWrapper: React.FC<PressableWrapperProps> = ({
  style,
  disabledOpacity = 0.3,
  activeOpacity = 0.2,
  duration = 50,
  disabled,
  onPressIn,
  onPressOut,
  children,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const fadeAnimRef = useRef(new Animated.Value(1));
  // manually set pressed state, as there is a bug with the animated Pressable component;
  // the style and children callbacks will somehow never be invoked
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);

  const fadeIn = useCallback(
    (toValue: number) => {
      Animated.timing(fadeAnimRef.current, {
        toValue,
        duration,
        easing: Easing.linear,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    },
    [duration],
  );

  const fadeOut = useCallback(() => {
    Animated.timing(fadeAnimRef.current, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, [duration]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (disabled) {
      fadeAnimRef.current.stopAnimation();
    } else {
      fadeOut();
    }
  }, [disabled, fadeOut]);

  return (
    <AnimatedPressable
      style={[
        { opacity: disabled ? disabledOpacity : fadeAnimRef.current },
        typeof style === 'function' ? style({ pressed }) : style,
      ]}
      onPressIn={(event) => {
        setPressed(true);
        fadeIn(activeOpacity);
        onPressIn?.(event);
      }}
      onPressOut={(event) => {
        setPressed(false);
        fadeOut();
        onPressOut?.(event);
      }}
      disabled={disabled}
      {...restProps}
    >
      {typeof children === 'function' ? children({ pressed }) : children}
    </AnimatedPressable>
  );
};
```